# WooCommerce WP_Query meta data field sku join with custom table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, sku

I have a custom table for products price and stock. I want to show price and stock from this custom table. I can only join on "sku", there is no post id in my custom table.

My `wp_custom_table` table column fields:

```
|   ct_id   |   ct_sku    |  ct_price   |   ct_stock    |
| (some id) | (sku value) | (sku value) | (stock value) |
```

WooCommerce `wp_post_meta` table column fields (and related values):

```
|    ID      |   post_id    |  meta_key  |  meta_value  |
| (some id)  | (product id) |   '_sku'   |  (sku value) |
```

How can I override woocommerce products query?

Comment: ct_id is auto incremented. There is no post id in my custom table. I can only use "ct_sku"

Comment: You can use a custom table in a `WP_Query`, but it's complicated and too broad with the provided code and informations in your question…

The following thread from WordPress Development StackExchange explains it: [How to extend WP_Query to include custom table in query?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50305/how-to-extend-wp-query-to-include-custom-table-in-query)

Comment: Much appreciated. That is the solution. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have completed this by setting up cron job. Cron job will update product prices from my custom table in bulk.